# How to create a nested array from csv rows using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to figure how to load my csv rows into a nested array.

For e.g., my csv file:

| id | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 | c1 | c2 | d1 | d2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 3 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

How do I make it into an array like this:

for each row I want to group every two columns into what I am showing below:

```
[ 
  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]],          #row 1
  [[9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]],   #row 2
  [[17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]],  #row 3
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nested list for all columns in pairs without `id` column use:

```
df = df.drop('id', axis=1)

L = np.reshape(df.to_numpy(), (len(df.index),len(df.columns) // 2,2)).tolist()
print (L)
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
 [[9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]],
 [[17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]]]
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but what if I don't have an id column? I was just using it to illustrate the number of rows

Comment: @Gbeck - then remove `df = df.drop('id', axis=1)
`

Comment: can you explain this line L = np.reshape(df.to_numpy(), (len(df.index),len(df.columns) // 2,2)).tolist()?

Comment: @Gbeck - Sure, `len(df.index)` number of rows, `len(df.columns) // 2` number of rows divide 2 and `2` for groups lenght

Answer (score 0):

Group the dataframe by index i.e. `level=0` (*can be avoided if no duplicate entries in dataframe for any index*), then for each group, filter the dataframe to get the pair of columns, then apply `list` on `axis=1` for each filtered dataframe, finally concatenate all of these on `axis=1`, then apply list again on `axis=1`, finally call `tolist()`:

```py
(df.groupby(level=0)
.apply(lambda x:pd.concat([x.filter(like=c)
                          .apply(list, axis=1) for c in 'abcd'], axis=1)
       )
.apply(list, axis=1)
.tolist()
 )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[
    [
        [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]
    ], 
    [
        [9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]
    ], 
    [
        [17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]
    ]
]
```